# Example of Linear-fractional function

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

This is a novice question I guess. Linear-fractional functions are defined as: 
$f(x) = (Ax + b) / (c^Tx + d)$
where, $dom f = \{ x|c^Tx + d > 0 \}$.

Although I understand the definition here, but I cant differentiate between $A$ and $c^T$. Since they are both matrix, why are they written in different style? Can someone provide any simple example of this?

Comment: In this definition $c$ is a column vector, and $d$ is a scalar, so the denominator is a scalar too.

Comment: The notation would imply that $c$ is a vector and $d$ is a scalar while $A$ is a matrix and $b$ is a vector.  Thus the numerator is a vector and the denominator is a scalar, and $f$ is a function that maps $R^{n}$ to $R^{m}$.